# Trying to update the value of a specific key in a custom dictionary (C++)

Tags: c++, list, visual-studio, dictionary, hashtable

So I am trying to go through my dictionary, which is made up of buckets of lists (mTable) and those lists are made up of Pairs (Key key, Value value). The function is given a const Key&, that is hashed, to look for within the specified bucket. It is also given a const Value&.

If the key is not found, the given Key& and Value& are to be paired together and added to the list at the specified bucket.

When the key is found however, all that needs to be done is update the current value to the one passed into the function.

Individually both conditionals work as intended. However once both conditionals coexist, the  condition checking if the key already exists within the bucket, is trying to add the new pair as if the key does not exist.

```
void Insert(const Key& _key, const Value& _value) {
        
    int bucket = mHashFunc(_key);   
    for (auto _listIter = mTable[bucket].begin(); _listIter != mTable[bucket].end(); ++_listIter) {
            if (_listIter->key != _key) {
                mTable[bucket].push_back(Pair(_key, _value));
                break;
                
            }
            else if(_listIter->key == _key)
                _listIter->value = _value;
}
```

Comment: You add the pair if _any_ of the keys in the map doesn't match your new key which is trivially always the case if the map has two elements or more with different keys. Go through the logic of your loop and `if` construction with an example on paper or in a debugger and you will see why.

Comment: Given what you've described, the obvious implementation would be to use an `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>` in which case adding/updating the value would be written as `mySet[key] = newValue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your code is not consistent with the procedure you have described. In the case that the first element does not have the same key as what is being inserted, your code will insert a new pair and return even if there is a pair with the same key further in the bucket list. Try the following instead.

```cpp
void Insert(const Key& _key, const Value& _value) {
    int bucket = mHashFunc(_key);
    for (auto _listIter = mTable[bucket].begin(); _listIter != mTable[bucket].end(); _listIter++) {
        if(_listIter->key == _key) {
            _listIter->value = _value;
            return;
        }
    }
    mTable[bucket].push_back(Pair(_key, _value));
}
```

As an aside, putting an underscore at the beginning of parameter names and local variables is a fairly strange practice. It's important to follow popular guidelines and styles because it make your code be more readable to others, so I would recommend perusing the following document:
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yeah I think i was getting confused with what was happening.